# urlopen windows ftp error

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

This code works perfectly at linux, but windows at there are errors. What's wrong?

```
import urllib, urllib2

a = 'ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/stats/arin/delegated-arin-latest'

urllib.urlopen(a)
IOError: [Errno ftp error] proxy support for ftp protocol currently not implemented

urllib2.urlopen(a)
URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: >
```

Comment: Are you shure that a is a string ? According to the http://codespeak.net/svn/pypy/dist/lib-python/2.5.2/urllib.py this error is raised if a is not a string...

Comment: In [8]: type(a)
Out[8]: <type 'str'>

Comment: I recommend to trace the code at the provided url...

Comment: how? at linux I'v no this problems. maybe windows sockets or something like that?

Comment: put your code in a file "error.py" and use the python debugger with "python -m pdb error.py" and step through the code. That is what I would do.

Comment: I looked at the urlopen code. Maybe your internet explorer has some proxy settings which cause the problem

Comment: proxy..... damn.... ie.... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have some proxy settings in your Internet Explorer: Menu Extras->Internet Options, there Connections->"LAN settings" (or something similar). If you have a Proxy server setting, urllib will not work.